# Uncaught ReferenceError: Parse is not defined

Tags: javascript, url, url-rewriting, parse-platform, google-drive-api

I unexpectedly received the following error through the debugger when trying to execute parse.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Parse is not defined
```

I am pretty sure its well defined so not sure where the error derives from.

Essentially what happens here is that a long url gets converted into a short url using google url shorten and then parse grabs the shorten url and stores it.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeShort() 
{
   var longUrl=document.getElementById("longurl").value;
    var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
    'resource': {
      'longUrl': longUrl
    }
    });
    request.execute(function(response) 
    {

        if(response.id != null)
        {
            str ="<a href='"+response.id+"'>"+response.id+"</a>";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;

              Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");
           var PDFUpload = new Parse.Object("Scan");


     PDFUpload.set("PDFDocument", str);

    PDFUpload.save(null, 
     {
        success: function(uploadResult) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.

        },
        error: function(uploadResult, error) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
          // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
          alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
        }
     });

        }


        else
        {
            alert("error: creating short url");
        }

    });
 }


function load()
{
    gapi.client.setApiKey('ID'); //get your ownn Browser API KEY
    gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1',function(){});

}
window.onload = load;

</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"> </script>

<body>

URL: <input type="text" id="longurl" name="url" value="yahoo.com" /> <br/>
<input type="button" value="Create Short" onclick="makeShort();" /> <br/> <br/>


<div id="output"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

In particular, below is the conversation happens, and where I try to store the url to parse:

```
        if(response.id != null)
        {
            str ="<a href='"+response.id+"'>"+response.id+"</a>";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;

              Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");
           var PDFUpload = new Parse.Object("Scan");


     PDFUpload.set("PDFDocument", str);

    PDFUpload.save(null, 
     {
        success: function(uploadResult) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.

        },
        error: function(uploadResult, error) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
          // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
          alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
        }
     });

        }
```

Comment: If the browser is telling you that "Parse" is not defined, what makes you so sure that it is?

Comment: because I have used this same code elsewhere, and it seems to works fine. I think it could be due to where it is placed.

Comment: if you could help in any way i would appreciate

Comment: Is there some script you're supposed to import from parse.com? I don't see anything like that in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have this in another file but where is your code where you reference Parse http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.5.min.js ?

Maybe you are missing that and that's why you get the error.